# How to Create ObjectProperty with Jena?

Tags: java, jena, owl, ontology

I am trying to create an ObjectyProperty using Jena
this is my code

```
String ns = new String("http://hamzadje28.com/medicDiag.owl#");
    String baseURI = new String("http://hamzadje28.com/medicDiag.owl#");

    Ontology ontoDiag = modelDiag.createOntology(baseURI);

    OntClass desease = modelDiag.createClass(ns+"Desease");
    OntClass symptom = modelDiag.createClass(ns+"Symptom");

    desease.addDisjointWith(symptom);
    symptom.addDisjointWith(desease);

    DatatypeProperty name = modelDiag.createDatatypeProperty(ns+"name");
    ObjectProperty hasSymptom = modelDiag.createObjectProperty(ns+"hasSymptom");
```

**my Question :**

How to create **Individuals** ,relate between them (ObjectProperty) and finally Create the **OWL file.**
Thank You.

Comment: Your topic is called "How to Create ObjectProperty with Jena?
" but in the question itself you're asking totally different hings. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Have you looked into the documentation? https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/#instances-or-individuals And you don''t need an `Ontology` node, `modelDiag` is already an OntModel.

Comment: No response from your side here but you opened a new question?!

Comment: I am sorry, I asked the other question because I still have the same problem.

Comment: Best practice would be to answer here the comments first.